# .NET4 JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize throws "Invalid object passed in, member name expected" on blank member names

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

On .NET4 attempting to use JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize a piece of json with an empty member name gives this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid object passed in, member name expected.
```

The following code will give the error:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
json.Deserialize<dynamic>("{'':0}");
```

On .NET4.5 no error and it deserializes successfully.

I'm generally failing to determine if this is fixed in .NET4 via patch/hotfix or otherwise.  Does anyone know if its fixed?

I am trying to fix this on a windows server 2003 SP2 machine, which can not be upgraded to 4.5, without success.

I have an alternative solution using JSON.NET and will use that if fix is unavailable for .NET4.

Comment: Facing the same issue.  Did you switch to JSON.NET as your solution?

Comment: Yes, had to move to JSON.NET.  I consoled myself that this was probably a good thing anyway.